# Is there a way to exclude some paths from the Quarkus OIDC verification

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I'm using the quarkus-oidc component to enforce the JWT token validation in calls to a microservice.

The point is there are some paths (`/api/public/*`) that can be invoked publicly (without needing an Authorization: Bearer JWT).

Is there a way to exclude paths from the token verification?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorization) you can disable authorization for select paths like this:

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.permit1.paths=/api/public/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.permit1.methods=GET,HEAD
quarkus.http.auth.permission.permit1.policy=permit
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've added that configuration but public paths still return a 401: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
`

Comment: Did you try adding the `methods` config as well? I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I just tried with the same result :( This may be a bug, I've opend an issue in github: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14001